# populate placeholders for a column with values dynamically

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, substitution, execute-immediate

I have the following table structure that holds error codes and related error messages:

```
ERR_CODE    ERR_MESSAGE
CN001       Invalid Username :USERNM
CN002       Invalid Password :PWD
```

In my PLSQL code, i would like to dynamically substitute the values for username and password.

I understand that EXECUTE IMMEDIATE can do substitutions by the USING clause but the query has to be static in that case.

I am looking for a flavor similar to execute immediate wherein can do this:

```
SIMILAR_EXECUTE_IMMDIATE q'{select ERR_MESSAGE from ERROR_MESSAGES where ERR_CODE = 'CN001'}' INTO l_err_msg USING l_curr_user;
```

OR maybe i can break it down in to 2 steps:

```
select ERR_MESSAGE into err_msg_var from ERROR_MESSAGES where ERR_CODE='CN001';

EXECUTE_IMMDIATE err_msg_var INTO l_err_msg USING l_curr_user;
```

Basically, I am trying to reduce the number of steps involved or maybe get a better performing query or approach.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Not sure that I'd want any system reporting a user's password in plaintext in any context. Your system should process the password and then discard it without logging it or exposing it in an error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, `execute immediate` statement will be of no help in this situation. Besides there is really no need to use it - everything(select list, table names) is known at compile time, it only comes down to the string substitution. Use static query, not dynamic. In order to do the substitution(or string formatting) you have at least two choices:

1. Simply use `replace()` function:

   ```
   set serveroutput on;
   clear screen;

   declare
      l_result varchar2(50);
   begin
      select err_message
        into l_result
        from error_messages
       where err_code = 'CN001';

      dbms_output.put_line(replace(l_result, ':USERNM', 'new value')); 
   end;
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   Invalid Username new value
   ```
2. If it possible, update `err_message` column of your `error_messages` table by replacing `:USERNM` and `:PWD` and other similar sub-strings thta denote placeholders with `%s`(placeholder for a character literal) or `%d` (placeholder for an integer literal if you have any) and use [utl_lms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/u_lms.htm#ARPLS71190) package and specifically `format_message()` function:

   ```
   set serveroutput on;
   clear screen;

   declare
     l_result varchar2(50);
   begin
     select err_message
       into l_result
       from error_messages
      where err_code = 'CN001';

     dbms_output.put_line(
        utl_lms.format_message(l_result, 'new_value_goes_here')
      ); 
   end;
   ```

   Result:

   ```
   Invalid Username new_value_goes_here
   ```

Comment: Thanks Nicholas ! The second approach sounds good to me. I used similar stuff in Java (MessageFormat.format()), never knew they had similar one in DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can just get the ERR_MESSAGE from your table via SELECT and append userName or PWD to it. Below is a snippet.

```
select ERR_MESSAGE into err_msg_var from ERROR_MESSAGES where ERR_CODE='CN001';
dbms_output.put_line(err_msg_var||l_curr_user)
```

You may return value of `dbms_output` if you want to define this as a function.